# A Not-So-Basic riddle

Tags: riddle

> Made of a number, a Kolkata train,
>
> My purposes now seem so plain.
>
> And though I seem to scream and shout,
>
> It's data and numbers I care about.
>
> -
>
> You used to love me, it's tried and true.
>
> Not much to see now, nor much to do.
>
> And though my fans became such hacks,
>
> I sent some to the moon and back.

Hint #1:

> Try to assemble the language used to find the pattern and solve the riddle!

Hint #2:

> Yes, the title is a hint.

Hint #3:

> You can use Google translate for the first line if you'd like. I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are

> The FORTRAN programming language.

Made of a number, a Kolkata train,

> Four is a number; the Bengali word for train is ট্রেন (ṭrēn)

My purposes now seem so plain.

> FORTRAN seems unsophisticated compared to modern programming languages

And though I seem to scream and shout,

> The name is generally written in ALL CAPS

It's data and numbers I care about.

> Used for programming.

You used to love me, it's tried and true.
Not much to see now, nor much to do.

> FORTRAN used to be widely used, but has been replaced by other languages and is now pretty obscure.

And though my fans became such hacks,

> You can still hack with FORTRAN :)

I sent some to the moon and back.

> Not sure about this one... was it used in the Apollo computer?

Title: A Not-So-Basic riddle

> BASIC is another programming language, partly based on FORTRAN

Comment: I thought no one was going to get it! Well done +1

Answer (score 2):

Are you a

> Rocket

Made of a number, a Kolkata train,

My purposes now seem so plain.

> ?

And though I seem to scream and shout,

It's facts I care so much about.

> It goes very fast and you may scream, but it is for a serious purpose unlike a roller coaster.

You used to love me, it's tried and true.

Not much to see, nor much to do.

> ?

And though my fans became such hacks,

> Maybe Hackers/Programmers like them?

I sent some to the moon and back.

> Yep, that is how it was done.

Title

> Nost so easy may seem like "it's not rocket science".

Comment: Nope, not what I was thinking :)

Comment: Oh well, I couldn't think of what to add to the "?".. :D